# A vectorized solution producing a new column in DataFrame that depends on conditions of existing columns and also the new column itself

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

My current dataframe data is as follows:

`df=pd.DataFrame([[1.4,3.5,4.6],[2.8,5.4,6.4],[7.8,6.5,5.8]],columns=['t','i','m'])`

```
    t   i   m
0  14  35  46
1  28  54  64
2  28  34  64
3  78  65  58
```

My goal is to apply a vectorized operations on a df with a conditions as follows (pseudo code):

New column of answer starts with value of 1.

```
For row in df.itertuples():
    if (m > i) & (answer in row-1 is an odd number):
        answer in row = answer in row-1 + m
    elif (m > i):
        answer in row = answer in row-1 - m
    else:
        answer in row = answer in row-1
```

The desired output is as follows:

```
    t   i   m  answer
0  14  35  46       1
1  28  54  59      60
2  78  12  58       2
3  78  91  48       2
```

Any elegant solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please add more detail about what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to create a new column 'answer' to the existing df such that the value to be filled depends on:
1) if value of m > i for that row; AND
2) if the value of this new column from its previous row is an odd number or not.

For each row of the df, if value of m > value i (say for row 1, 59 > 54, so it is true) AND the value of the last row of column answer (yes, the new column) is an odd number (the value of 'answer' in row 0 is 1 which is an odd number), then the value of  the new column 'answer' will be equal to its own previous value plus value of m of that row (i.e. 1 + 59) = 60

Comment: However, in row 2, while m > i (58 >12), the value of 'answer' (the new column) from its own previous row (i.e. row 1) is NOT an odd number and so the value of 'answer' for row 2 = 60 (value of 'answer' from previous row, i.e. row 1) - 58 (i.e. m value of row 2) = 2

Comment: @Suit Boy Apps Any luck on the solution?

Comment: No. I have been at school all day and am now doing homework. I’m probably not going to be the guy who’ll solve this because it has been two years since the last time I used python to develop anything. I’ve only used it here and there to make programs to run small cost vs profit calculators. After I’m done with my homework I’ll take a deeper look into it and see if I can maybe point you in the right direction

Comment: Can you please explain the answer that you are trying to get to me some more? From your code the answer that I am expecting is often off by 10 or more then the desired output you have listed. Lets move to chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150130/discussion-between-suit-boy-apps-and-user7786493).